# Call a method, renaming the variables as new one

Tags: java, variables, methods

I'm working on a small project, I want to make code a lot shorted, and easier, rather than writing it out multiple times. I have a method shown below, I want to use this method multiple times - but every String that is stored in the Text Field has to be kept - and not replaced. Eg.

- The variable tf1 = "item1"
- I Then call the method again, the variable tf1 is than changed to tf1 = "item2"
- I want tf1 to keep both "item1" and "item2"

Method:

```
public static void text(){
    TextField tf1 = new TextField();
}
text();
```

Comment: Please clarify. If you're asking how to change a variable's name at runtime, that's easy to answer: in Java as in most compiled languages, you can't. My guess is that you want to fill some collection, perhaps an ArrayList or HashMap, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: unclear what you are asking?

Comment: When you enter a method, any variables you declare in the method get allocated newly. In order to get some information from a method into a subsequent invocation of that method you would have to return something to the caller who would then have to pass you back that information in a subsequent invocation.

Comment: Use an array of objects, just make sure the program can remember what is at each index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use a list of String type. 
A list would enable you to hold infinite data of the same type while keeping it under the same name since a list dynamically grows in size. 
you can then use an iterator or a for-each loop to access the data stored in the list.

The general syntax would be: `List<String> textFieldList=new ArrayList<String>();`

P.S. Remember to use the List of java.util package.

Comment: Thank you very much - this helped a lot (sorry for not explaining too well)

Comment: @ScottHollas: and still you never improved the question and ignored all comments to your question: Why? I'm afraid that this is not a good start for you on this site. Please go through the [help] and the [tour] sections so that hopefully your future questions will be better. You can still improve this question so that it makes sense.

Comment: better? @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correct, I would do in the below way.

```
TextField tf[] = new TextField[100];
int clickCount = 0;

public static void text(){

tf[clickCount] = new TextField();
clickCount++;
```

}

You can initialize tf[] with the number you want. 
If you are not aware of the number, 
You can go for an ArrayList

Comment: Hi - What is the 100 used for in []

Comment: 100 is just an example for n to initialize an array at start

Answer (score 0):

An ArrayList of String type probably help your code.

ArrayList TextField =new ArrayList();

TextField.add("item1");
TextField.add("item2");